# How do I modify this VBA script to extract only rows within the specified date range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA script, where I would like to filter based on the 3rd column - StartDate :

```
Sub RemDates()
Dim RowToTest As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
  For RowToTest = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1  
    With ws.Cells(RowToTest, 3)
      If .Value > #12/24/2016# _
        And .Value < #12/29/2016# Then _
          ws.Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
  Next RowToTest
Next
End Sub
```

But this is not working correctly.  The following is a screenshot of my spreadsheet (which I want to filter ) .

[image]

Any tips appreciated ,  thanks

Comment: What goes wrong? I am assuming this goes wrong because you loop through the rows and within that loop you delete rows, which harms the loop.

Comment: Are the values in the column stored as dates or text?

Comment: @tompreston  - I think it's as "Custom" ( a CSV file ) - in excel when I right-click and choose "properties " that's what comes up

Comment: Infact, I'm not sure what's wrong with the circled cell?  Its value doesn't meet the criteria to be deleted, you may want to use an 'or' in place of the 'and'?

Comment: @tompreston - Apologies, I really just meant to indicate the whole column there. Nothing wrong with that specific cell

Comment: @tompreston - fixed the pic

Comment: Not a problem.  Your code is saying if the value is between 12/24/2016 and 12/29/2016 then delete the row, is this definitly what you want?  All the values in the column seem to be fine?

Comment: @tompreston   -  Actually the logic was reversed in my mind. I changed it to be `If .Value2 < #12/26/2016# _     Or .Value2 > #12/30/2016# _     Then _`  , which gets the results I need.  Thanks !